# Heroku Rails 4 Timezone ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have deployed an application to Heroku. The application will only display UTC time back out, despite the fact that I have

```
config.time_zone = 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
```

Set in my app config, I have also added the key to the heroku app of

```
heroku config:add TZ="America/Denver"
```

Neither of these values make a difference and all time is still displayed out in UTC.

I have a small method to display the time back out in a string format, it works fine locally, how can I get this to display the time in MST?

```
  def prettify_time(dt)
    if dt.present?
     "#{dt.strftime("%-I:%M %p") } in #{distance_of_time_in_words DateTime.now, dt}"
    else
     ""
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are assigning `dt` but I don't think `DateTime.now` will give you a local time. Try `DateTime.current` instead.

```
Rails.application.config.time_zone => "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"
DateTime.current => Wed, 05 Nov 2014 10:29:46 -0700
DateTime.now => Wed, 05 Nov 2014 17:29:51 +0000
```